# How can I break a row to multiple rows based on interval

Tags: r, dplyr, intervals

My data looks like this:

```
das <- data.frame(val=1:3,
                  beginning =c(10,20,40),
                  end=c(20,40,51))
```

```
  val beginning end
1   1        10  20
2   2        20  40
3   3        40  51
```

I want to break each row to 3 rows by dividing the beginning to end to equal parts. like this

Expected output

```
> das
  val beginning end
1   1        10  13
2   2        13  16
3   3        16  20
4   4        20  27
5   5        27  34
6   6        34  40
7   7        40  44
8   8        44  48
9   9        48  51
```

I came across similar questions here, but most of them are w.r.t to date range.

Comment: Where are the new values for `val` coming from? Also, you say you want equal sizes, but you have split the first entry into periods that are 3, 3, and 4 apart. How did you decide to split it that way instead of either dividing by 3, or, for example, dividing it 4, 3, 3 or 3, 4, 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `uncount()` in `tidyr` and then calculate the increment of each `val`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

das %>%
  uncount(3) %>% 
  mutate(beginning = beginning + round((end - beginning)/3) * 0:2,
         end = lead(beginning, default = last(end)))

#   val beginning end
# 1   1        10  13
# 2   1        13  16
# 3   1        16  20
# 4   2        20  27
# 5   2        27  34
# 6   2        34  40
# 7   3        40  44
# 8   3        44  48
# 9   3        48  51
```

Comment: this works great. never came across uncount(). If I want to break each row to 5 rows then I change the division to 5 ?

Comment: @Gerg Yes, and replace `0:2` with `0:4`.

Answer (score 1):

```
n_intervals <- 3

rows <- split(das, seq_len(nrow(das)))

res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(rows, function(row) {
  timesplits <- seq(from = row$beginning, 
                    to = row$end, 
                    length.out = n_intervals + 1)
  data.frame(beginning = head(timesplits, -1),
             end = tail(timesplits, -1))
}))

res$val <- seq_len(nrow(res))

#>     beginning      end val
#> 1.1  10.00000 13.33333   1
#> 1.2  13.33333 16.66667   2
#> 1.3  16.66667 20.00000   3
#> 2.1  20.00000 26.66667   4
#> 2.2  26.66667 33.33333   5
#> 2.3  33.33333 40.00000   6
#> 3.1  40.00000 43.66667   7
#> 3.2  43.66667 47.33333   8
#> 3.3  47.33333 51.00000   9
```